# How do I reset all my filters / labels / categories on Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-categories

I have a considerable number of Social and Promotions emails that keep going into the Spam folder, and many others are wrongly assigned to Updates and Promotions while they should be in Primary.

How do I reset everything to default settings so that then I can decide what goes where?

Comment: Are these being controlled by filters?

Comment: No, I haven't set up any explicit filters, it's just Gmail trying to guess where my mail should go.

Comment: Okay so would you like to get rid of the Social and Promotions or un-mark spam?

Answer (score 2):

> 1st step delete any filters that might have been setup (Found under settings > filters)

[image: Gmail Filter Settings]

> 2nd step only enable the tabs you want (Under main Gmail page)

[image: Gmail Tabs]
[image: Gmail Tabs selection page]

> 3rd and last step go to your spam folder > select all and press not spam

[image: Gmail Not spam]

From here you will have removed all unwanted filters and marked everything that isn't spam as not spam for Gmail and you can manage what is and isn't from there

Note:

I'm unaware of any way completely disabling Gmail's built in spam filter

Work around search `in:anywhere is:spam` select all and mark not spam periodically

Comment: A fourth step would be to drag any messages that are under the wrong tab to the correct tab. This will train Gmail to learn what messages go where.